# l3doc adds unwanted backslash in margin box of {function}

Tags: expl3, package-writing, documentation

I'm using `l3doc` for documenting some packages (I know it is not officially stable, but I like it …). I came to the problem that `{function}{<list>}` adds a backslash for every item in `<list>` if one of the items is a macro starting with a backslash.

```
\documentclass{l3doc}

\begin{document}

\begin{function}{{environment}}
Description
\end{function}
\begin{function}{\command}
Description
\end{function}
\begin{variable}{counter}
Description
\end{variable}
\begin{function}{{environmentII}, counterII, \commandII}
Description for multiple items
\end{function}

\begin{macro}{{environment}}
Definition
\end{macro}
\begin{macro}{\command}
Definition
\end{macro}
\begin{macro}{counter}
Definition
\end{macro}
\begin{macro}{{environmentII}, counterII, \commandII}
Description for multiple items
\end{macro}

\end{document}
```

The example shows that using a single item in `<list>` works as expected but as soon as I add a macro to the list all items are *backslashed*. `{macro}` doesn’t show this behavior …

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you are simply misusing the environment. The expected argument is either a function or a list of functions. But none of the elements in the list you pass is a function in l3's sense. (But the environment *may* be intended to document-level commands as well - see below. In that case, *some* of the things you are passing are functions, but not others.)

Note that even in the cases where you say that it works as expected, you are not getting items consistently formatted. For example, you get `counter` formatted in serif font - not typewriter - because it does not look like a variable to the parser. (`\l_tobi_counter_int` would presumably work here and is the l3 equivalent.)

The code which defines the various environments provided by **l3doc** processes the arguments according to the expected syntax for the types of things the environment is intended to document.

So, for example, the `function` environment looks for the `:` in each element in the comma-separated list in order to separate the name from the specification of its arguments. This information is then automatically processed and formatted in the standard way.

For example,

```
\begin{function}{\Tobi_function_one:nn, \Tobi_function_one:Vn, \Tobi_function_one:VV}
Description for multiple items
\end{function}
```

will detect that it is dealing with three variants of the same function i.e. cases where variants of the base function have been generated in the usual way. It will then format the first as the basic variant and the remaining two as variants, combining them and distinguishing their different argument specifiers.

[image: variant functions]

A comma-separated list is intended for cases where the listed items are minor variations on a theme e.g. the same function with different argument specifications or a variant form of some sort. But an environment, a counter and a macro are not of this kind and ought not be grouped together in this way.

I am not entirely certain what `macro` should be used for. I can't find much documentation for **l3doc** and I've not been able to figure out from the source of the documentation for l3 what exactly the distinction is supposed to be.

My first thought was that `macro` might be intended for document-level commands but, despite what I said above, **xparse**'s documentation uses `function` to document document-level commands. This is confusing to me because I did not think that these commands were *functions* at all. I thought this was part of the idea in distinguishing document-level stuff from the lower-level l3 stuff, and that 'functions' applied only to the latter. But I am obviously mistaken about this. (And, of course, `macro` wouldn't necessarily make much sense either, since functions are certainly macros.)

Here's the example code I was playing with.

```
\documentclass{l3doc}
\begin{document}
\begin{function}{\Tobi_function_prior:n}
  Description
\end{function}
\begin{function}{\command:}
  Description
\end{function}
\begin{variable}{\l_Tobi_variable_tl}
  Description
\end{variable}
\begin{function}{\Tobi_function_one:nn, \Tobi_function_one:Vn, \Tobi_function_one:VV}
  Description for multiple items
\end{function}
\begin{function}{\TobiDocumentCommand}
  \begin{syntax}
    \cs{TobiDocumentCommand}\marg{mandatory argument}
  \end{syntax}
\end{function}
\end{document}
```

[image: l3 documentation experiment]

Comment: {macro} is basically inherited from ltxdoc with a few bells and whistles to interface to {function} — i.e., it's used to document the actual code definition of the function. There's no technical requirement to use expl3-style functions — it just ignores any formatting niceties in that case. As Joseph is fond of saying, l3doc needs an overhaul; it's really only designed for one thing: documenting expl3 and friends.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! In that case I guess I’ll implement a new environment for my docs … there’s one thing I can’t follow in your answer: “For example, you get counter formatted in serif font - not typewriter - because it does not look like a variable to the parser.” It is in typewriter, isn’t it …?

Comment: @WillRobertson `... it's really only designed for one thing: documenting expl3 and friends` is what I figured. That is, looking at the code, that seemed likely. I couldn't see the expl3-style functions being a requirement i.e. it seemed to work, **xparse**'s docs used it etc. I was just stumped by what `macro` might be for. But that makes sense. (I never use the l2 version of this stuff, so I just took it from the OP's code that it was intended for something-like-this. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Tobi When I ran your original code, some of it seemed to be in serif rather than typewriter - maybe the first `counter` where you have just `counter` in the argument to `variable`. Maybe my eyes deceived me, but that's how it looked.

Comment: @cfr: Strange … on my system everything is in tt font …